# Constant $f:[\mathbb{N}]^2\to \{1,2\}$.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, graph-theory

Let $[\mathbb{N}]^2$ denote the set collection in size $2$. Now, let $f:[\mathbb{N}]^2\to \{1,2\}$.

How can one show that, if we fixing some $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then there exist infinite set $R_1\subseteq {\mathbb{N}-\{n\}}$ such that $f$ is constant on sets of the form $\{n,r_1 \}$ where $r\in R_1$ .

Comment: What is "set collection in size $2$"? If you mean the set of unordered pairs, then $\binom{\Bbb N}2$ (pronounced $\Bbb N$ choose $2$) would be a more understandable notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing $n\in\Bbb N$, there are infinitely many $r\in\Bbb N\smallsetminus\{n\}$, and so infinitely many sets $\{n,r\}$ with $r\in\Bbb N\smallsetminus\{n\}$. Now, each $\{n,r\}$ is mapped to either $1$ or $2$. If there were only finitely many $\{n,r\}$ mapping to $1$ and only finitely many $\{n,r\}$ mapping to $2$, then since a union of two finite sets is finite, we would only have finitely many $\{n,r\}$ to begin with, which we've already seen is not the case. Hence, there are infinitely many $\{n,r\}$ mapping to $1$ or there are infinitely many $\{n,r\}$ mapping to $2$.

If there are infinitely many $r$ such that $f$ maps $\{n,r\}\mapsto 1$, then we let $$R_1=\left\{r\in\Bbb N:\{n,r\}\in f^{-1}\bigl(\{1\}\bigr)\right\}.$$ Otherwise, we let $$R_1=\left\{r\in\Bbb N:\{n,r\}\in f^{-1}\bigl(\{2\}\bigr)\right\}.$$

Comment: Actually, $R_1 = \{r:\{n,r\}\in f^{-1}(\{1\})\}$, isn't it? $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ is not a subset of $\mathbb N$

Comment: Ah! Right you are, Thomas.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews why "If not, then there must be only finitely many sets {n,r}, which is certainly not the case."?

Comment: @17SI.34SA: Because there are infinitely many $r\in\Bbb N\smallsetminus\{n\}$, and so there are infinitely many sets $\{n,r\}$ with $r\in\Bbb N\smallsetminus\{n\}$. All of these sets are mapped to either $1$ or $2$, but if only finitely many map to $1$ and only finitely many map to $2$, then there can be only finitely many to begin with (since the union of two finite sets is finite).

Comment: Thank you again! It's all clear now!

Comment: You're very welcome, @17SI.34SA. I'll add that explanation to my answer, as well.